# Book recommendation over Matrix Theory

Tags: matrices, reference-request, book-recommendation, matrix-calculus, matrix-rank

I am looking for a book that have some detailed proofs of the main results around some topics listed below:

- rank (maybe with some properties of matrices with constant rank)
- linear group
- special group (or unimodular group)
- continuity and differentiation of determinants (to prove that some groups are open)
- Orthogonal group
- connected components of these matrix groups

So the approach have to be wide and include analysis (calculus), topology, algebra and some geometry (topological and differentiable manifolds) with some isomorphisms/difeomorfisms/homeomorphisms with other objects like spheres, torus or other surfaces on euclidean spaces.

Comment: Naive lie theory to start. What is your background?

Comment: @Justin My background: linear algebra (3/4 of Hoffman), differential geometry (do Carmo), graduate algebra, graduate real analysis and graduate measure theory. I'm taking a Introductory Course on Differentiable Manifolds and the author uses some results (in examples) over matrix theory that I never seen before. So I am looking for a book more explanatory and with these properties detailed.

Comment: If you know graduate level analysis you should have no trouble showing that the locus where the determinant is non-zero is open?

Comment: @user2520938 No problem of course. But books with these kind of results may bring things that I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brian C. Hall's *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations* devotes a significant portion of the first chapter to specific matrix Lie groups, namely the general/special linear groups, (special and complex) orthogonal groups, (special) unitary groups, Lorentz groups, symplectic groups, Heisenberg group, Euclidean and Poincare groups, etc.

A few sections later, he investigates the connected components of many of these groups. So this might address some of the points you're looking for.